# Слишком много рекурсии

Tags: javascript

Продолжаю свои крестовый поход в мир JavaScript. Столкнулся со следующей трудностью:

```
function stub(callback){
        var delay = Math.floor(Math.random()*10000)+1000;
        var msg = "Message " + delay;
        setTimeout(stub(callback), delay);
        callback(msg);
}

stub( function( msg ){ alert(msg); });
```

Выполняю в firefox и firebug показывает ошибку:

```
too much recursion: setTimeout(stub(callback), delay);
```

Как-нибудь это можно обойти? Вроде рекурсией и не пахнет, лишь бесконечный цикл :-)

UPD. Другой косяк заметил задержку стал варьировать от 10000 до 30000 миллисекунд. но что-то я не ощущаю этой задержки, в чем может быть проблема?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Во-первых, вы неверно используете setTimeout. Вы передаёте в качестве первого параметра не функцию, а результат её выполнения. Это и приводит к тому, что нет задержки (в случае, если вы поменяли местами). А если всё так, как написано у вас, то вы вызываете stub из stub.. вот и получается рекурсия. (Вызываете stub, вместо того, чтобы сослаться на stub для вызова по таймауту).

UPD: Чтобы это победить, надо делать так:

```
function stub(callback){
    var delay = Math.floor(Math.random()*10000)+1000;
    var msg = "Message " + delay;

    setTimeout( function() {
        stub(callback); 
    }, delay);
    callback(msg);
}

stub( function( msg ) {
    alert(msg);
});
```

UPD2: "всё заработало"  - это не верно. Просто показывается alert и вы закрываете, заходите опять в рекурсию и опять алёрт.. просто не успевает стек переполниться :)

Comment: Верно подмечено.

Comment: Ещё одну функцию обертку добавить? :-D

Comment: alert() это так для примера :-)

Answer (score 2):

А в чем смысл функции и выполнения ее по таймеру?

Просто интересно как работает js?

Я бы решил текущую задачу так:

```
var i;
function stub(__callback) {
i++;
var msg = 'Message ' + i;
eval(__callback);
};
setInterval(function () { stub('any code place here'); }, 1000);
```

Если Вам интересно про js, то советую изначально использовать прототипы, вроде:

```
var Example = function(options) {
this.sample = options['some_option'];
this.__construct();
};
Example.prototype = {
sample: null,
__construct: function() {
alert(this.sample);
}
};
var test = new Example({some_option: 'test value'});
```

Функции - вещь хорошая, но когда нужно создавать кучу прототипов объекта, то лучше собственно прототипов ничего не придумаешь, это структура, которая имеет свои методы и св-ва. Советую для изучения :)

Comment: спасибо, но я ещё многово не осмыслил в js) изучаю по книге Джона Рейсига - "JavaScript - Профессиональные приемы программирования" ещё не дошел до прототипов :-)

Answer (score 0):

Поменял строки setTimeout(stub(callback), delay); c callback(msg); и всё заработало. 
Может у кого-нибудь есть советы как сделать это лучше?)
Кому интересно правильный вариант надеюсь :-)

```
function stub(callback){
        var delay = Math.floor(Math.random()*10000)+1000;
        var msg = "Message " + delay;
        callback(msg);
        setTimeout(function(){stub(callback)} , delay);
}

stub( function( msg ){ alert(msg); });
```